# What kind of training is the best, if you hava a competition the next day?

Tags: training

If you have some kind of sportive competition the next day, is it advisable to train?
What intensity, and what kind of training is advisable?

In my case it's a judo competition.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Currently the question is far too broad as each sport (and competition) is very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It is best to prepare mentally. Imagine the sports/activity thoroughly.
- Do the activity at lower intensity.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what the competition is? You don't want to deplete energy resources, so it's best to `rest` and make sure you eat properly ans `stay hydrated`.